# Reading file from php module fails with errno 13

Tags: php, linux, apache, module

Good day.
There is a PHP module ( .so) loaded within PHP. On MINIT stage it tries to read a file.
The file is a /tmp/aaa.txt
The directory /tmp belongs to root and its permissions are set to 777.
The file /tmp/aaa.txt belongs to apache user and is also set to 777 permissions.

Module opens the file with VCWD_FOPEN(), which is define for
`#define VCWD_FOPEN(path, mode) virtual_fopen(path, mode TSRMLS_CC)` which eventually is a fopen().

The `VCWD_FOPEN` fails with error 13 (permission denied).
The strange thing is, if I invoke the module manually 
`( #php -r 'echo "hi";' )` - it works.
But when it runs from apache - it doesnt.
Anybody knows why?

Thank you

Comment: try to run the same php command under the apache user and see what happens, looks like a permission issue to me

Comment: Can you try it by changing your apache user's group to one same as root's ?

Comment: If i print `getuid()` and `getgid()`, they are both 0 (meaning I'm root). And still getting access denied. If I put the file in /etc - it works. But not in /tmp. Strange :(

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.
The user permission policy was enforced by SELinux.
To disable it i typed
    `#setenforce 0`
    `#service httpd restart`

Works now

Comment: It is the reason for the error. The solution depends on what I need.